# PHP curl code stops working after a few requests Cent OS 7 server

Tags: php, apache, curl, centos7, digital-ocean

I created a droplet in Digital Ocean and I have a code in PHP that uses curl to scrape a specific page.

When I created the server and configured it, the code works fine, but after a few requests it stops working. The curl doesn't respond with the correct page, looks like there was a redirect to a wrong page.

I tried to destroy the droplet and start all over again, this time I created a snapshot of the droplet with code working, again after a few requests it stops working, I tried to restore to the snapshot, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know what is happening? I think is some wrong or missing configuration, but I don't figure out what is wrong.

I am using CentOS 7, apache, php 7.2

P.S.: The code works fine in other server that I use in a shared server in Hostgator, and works fine to in localhost.

Comment: Maybe the website you're scraping has some sort of anti-scraping protection?

Comment: I don't think so, because if I use the same code in localhost or in my other server I am able to scrape unlimited times.

Comment: Its clearly some sort of flood protection on the other server. Think about it, the code works on the first run, the code doesn't change so the code should work forever, the only thing which can now alter the result is the response of the other server. Bear in mind with no rate limiting your server can probably make 1000s of requests per second.

Comment: @miknik this is strange, because, if I make the request from the server on my shared server hosted in Hostgator, or if I make the requests in localhost, I can make "unlimeted" requests. but when I try with this vps in digital ocean I have problems, because that I think is a misconfiguration in my server but I can't figure out what is. If I destroy the droplet and start all over again it will work again for a short time. I tried a lot of things, tried to disable the fail2ban, tried to disable firewall, tried to disable SElinux, tried to disable mod_evasive, but without success.